# React AWS Ampify Auth fetchAuthSession returning undefined credentials

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, credentials

I have a React App that interfaces with AWS using the javascript v3 sdk. I'm also using `"aws-amplify": "^6.0.6"` for authentication. I've set up amplify and it's working great, but the problem is that I can't seem to get the credentials from Amplify/Auth to pass into other AWS resources like DynamoDB using:

```
const ddb = new DynamoDBClient({
    region: import.meta.env.VITE_AWS_REGION,
    credentials, // THIS IS WHAT I NEED
});
```

So far I have a higher order component wrapping my whole app:

```
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
...
export default withAuthenticator(APP);
```

according to https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/auth/auth-migration-guide/#authcurrentusercredentials-deprecated I should be able to get the credentials from using `const session = await fetchAuthSession();`

But my credentials are undefined...

my session looks like this:

```
{
    "credentials": undefined,
    "identityId": undefined,
    "tokens": {
        "accessToken": {
            "payload": {
                "sub": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx",
                "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "origin_jti": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "event_id": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "token_use": "access",
                "scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.role",
                "auth_time": 1702010502,
                "exp": 1702014102,
                "iat": 1702010502,
                "jti": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "username": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
            }
        },
        "idToken": {
            "payload": {
                "sub": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "email_verified": true,
                "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx",
                "cognito:username": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "origin_jti": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "aud": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "event_id": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "token_use": "id",
                "auth_time": 1702010502,
                "exp": 1702014102,
                "iat": 1702010502,
                "jti": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "email": "xxxxx@email.com"
            }
        },
        "signInDetails": {
            "loginId": "xxxxx@email.com",
            "authFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH"
        }
    },
    "userSub": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Is there something else I need to do to get the credentials object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using **Cognito Identity Pools**? If not, you should use them in order to get `credentials`.

This is how you can configure it in React app for existing Cognito resources. You have to set `identityPoolId` here.

```
// REQUIRED only for Federated Authentication - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab'
```

[image]

Refer [Set up and configure Amplify Auth - Existing Resources tab](https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/auth/set-up-auth/#set-up-and-configure-amplify-auth) for more detail.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4800344)

Comment: I am not using an identity pool, just a user pool. I'll give this a try and see if that fixes it. Thank you!

Comment: I just created an identity pool and hooked it up and it works! Thank you again for your help! I would upvote, but I guess I need 15 reputation to do that...

Comment: Ok, but can you please mark the answer as accepted? That doesn’t require minimum reputations as you are the original poster.

Comment: Hi i am only using userpool and clientid , but fetchauthsession returns undefined token. did i miss something in my configuration?

Comment: @James Refer my this answer which may help you -https://stackoverflow.com/a/77639669/1273882

Comment: I think above link is for react native, I am using for react project but ill try to check on it. thanks.