# Retrieve raw accessToken and idToken in aws-amplify js v6

Tags: react-native, authentication, jwt, aws-amplify

I am using `aws-amplify` v6 inside my react-native app.

Authentication functionality is working correctly however I could not access raw access/id tokens after login.

Trying to retrieve the tokens like:

```js
import { fetchAuthSession } from "aws-amplify/auth";

...

async getCurrentSession() {
      const session = await fetchAuthSession();
      console.log("Token: ", JSON.stringify(session.tokens?.idToken));
}
```

However, tokens inside the session are of the type of `JwtPayloadStandardFields`
and contain only parsed payloads of the tokens i.e.

```json
{
   "payload":{
      "sub":"4ac665ba-2e3c-40a0-93d8-515e2224fe22",
      "email_verified":true,
      "is":"...",
      "cognito:username":"...",
      "origin_jti":"c9f42d85-b7f2-4780-995a-562ff120d6c7",
      "aud":"...",
      "event_id":"2fe27904-8de0-4b53-80b5-abe166f98e9f",
      "token_use":"id",
      "auth_time":1701865836,
      "exp":1702047957,
      "iat":1702044358,
      "jti":"28516f62-0cab-4a5d-a6f1-eb6dff6cadee",
      "email":"xxx"
   }
}
```

I am wondering how to access actual **raw** tokens as I need them to pass to API clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I am using it in **Angular TypeScript** with **Amplify v6**.

1. Import `fetchAuthSession` on top.

   ```js
   import { fetchAuthSession } from "aws-amplify/auth";
   ```
2. Then, just apply `.toString()` method on `idToken` property.

   ```js
   var cognitoTokens = (await fetchAuthSession()).tokens;

   let rawToken = cognitoTokens?.idToken?.toString();
   let payload = cognitoTokens?.idToken?.payload;
   ```

   As you can see in the below screenshot, it offers 2 properties.

   [image]

   Here is a screenshot that I captured during debugging.

   [image]

> I am using `"aws-amplify": "^6.0.5"` version.

Comment: Both toString and payload methods return already parsed token attributes, not a raw token.

Comment: I just updated answer with a screenshot. Can you try once again. If it is working for me, it should work for you as well.

Comment: Yes, toString did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Hi may i know how were u able to return the values? when i tried fetchAuthSession it returns undefined for the values upon successful login. Is there additional configuration to be done? thanks

Comment: Are you using async await properly?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider` after you config [token-saving](https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/auth/manage-user-session/#update-your-token-saving-mechanism) properly

It can use like this.

```
    import { cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider } from 'aws-amplify/auth/cognito'

    const {idToken, accessToken, refreshToken, ..., username} = await cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider.authTokenStore.loadTokens()
```

[image]

I am using  "aws-amplify": "^6.0.10"